# Iterators in Ada

Tags: ada

How can I write an iterator in a procedure?
Sorry for my dump question, I am novoice.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It totally depends on what you need to iterate over.

An array?  Use a [loop](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-5-5.html): plain, for, or while.

One of the [predefined containers](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18.html)?  Use the iterator declarations associated with the container.

A string? Treat it like an array.

It would help if you provided more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Ada style guide](http://www.adaic.org/docs/95style/html/sec_8/8-3-6.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Ada 95 Rationale. There is an example there of an iterator which you might use as a starting point. Look here: http://www.adahome.com/LRM/95/Rationale/rat95html/rat95-p2-3.html#7

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked, Ada 2012 came out, which now has proper support for user-defined iterators. You can now say:

```
for i of Some_Random_Object loop
  -- do stuff with i
end loop;
```

Details [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-3.html) and [here](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-128-iterators-in-ada-2012-part-2).

Answer (score 0):

Well, like others have said, it depends...

Personally, in my current project I find myself doing stuff like this quite a lot:

```
for Thing in 1..Number_Of_Things loop
 -- do stuff here
end loop;
```